# How to record a udp stream of audio to a wav file using QT

Tags: qt, udp, streaming, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am using QT and I am looking to record a udp stream to a wav file. I can not use the QAudioRecorder library since I am receiving samples of data and not receiving the audio through an Input device

I can not seem to playback the audio file after the data and header has been written to it.

here is my header:

```
header.riff[0] = 'R';
header.riff[1] = 'I';
header.riff[2] = 'F';
header.riff[3] = 'F';
header.size_of_payload = 0;
header.wave[0] = 'W';
header.wave[1] = 'A';
header.wave[2] = 'V';
header.wave[3] = 'E';
header.fmt[0] = 'F';
header.fmt[1] = 'M';
header.fmt[2] = 'T';
header.fmt[3] = ''; // trailing NULL
header.len_of_format = 0x10;
header.format_tag = 0x01;
header.channels = 0x01;
header.sample_rate = 8000;
header.bytes_per_second = 8000;
header.bytes_per_sample = 1;
header.bits_per_sample = 8;
header.data_ident[0] = 'd';
header.data_ident[1] = 'a';
header.data_ident[2] = 't';
header.data_ident[3] = 'a';
header.len_of_data = filesize - 44;
```

The receiving udp packets written to file: recorder.cpp

```
recorder::recorder()
{
   sock = new QUdpSocket(this);
   sock->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost,1234);
   file.setFileName("audioFile.wav");
   file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

   connect(sock,SIGNAL(readReady),this, SLOT(readReady()));
}

// runs every time data is received on the udp socket
recorder::readReady()
{
   QByteArray audio_data;
   audio_data.resize(sock->pendingDatagramSize());
   sock->readDatagram(audio_data.data(),audio_data.size());
   // write data as it comes in on the socket
   file.write(audio_data,audio_data.size());
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to to? Record the UDP stream to a file? Playing it back? Playing back the recorded file? Some code could also help.

Comment: I am trying to record the udp stream to a file. Then play it back. I have seen that my header type length_of_data was set to zero which was allowing the audio not to play back. I changed it to filesize - 44, which 44 is the length of the data..now I am getting audio but all static audio

Comment: I updated the question to provide more insight and code @SteakOverflow